iOS Bug: Content in position: sticky with writing-mode: vertical-rl Disappears Intermittently
I'm experiencing an intermittent issue on iOS when using position: sticky in combination with writing-mode: vertical-rl. The content inside elements with position: sticky sometimes disappears and then reappears when the page is loaded or when scrolling vertically or horizontally.
Please let me know how to avoid this problem or any alternatives.
DEMO on Netlify
HTML：
<div class="container">
    <div class="group">
        <h2 class="sticky">Fruits</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Apple harvest has begun</li>
            <li>A new variety of grapes has been introduced</li>
            <li>Orange imports are increasing</li>
            <li>The nutritional value of bananas is being reassessed</li>
            <li>The mango season has arrived</li>
            <li>Cherry prices are rising</li>
            <li>The health benefits of pineapples</li>
            <li>How to chill watermelon</li>
            <li>New melon recipes</li>
            <li>Strawberry storage methods</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <h2 class="sticky">Vegetables</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Tomato cultivation techniques are evolving</li>
            <li>A new variety of cucumbers is gaining attention</li>
            <li>The health benefits of cabbage are being reassessed</li>
            <li>How to keep lettuce fresh</li>
            <li>The nutritional value of carrots has improved</li>
            <li>Broccoli cooking methods</li>
            <li>Spinach storage methods</li>
            <li>A bountiful potato harvest</li>
            <li>Eggplant popularity is surging</li>
            <li>Bell pepper cooking ideas</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <h2 class="sticky">Meat</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Beef consumption is increasing</li>
            <li>New cooking methods for pork</li>
            <li>Chicken prices are stable</li>
            <li>Lamb popularity is rising</li>
            <li>The health impacts of bacon</li>
            <li>Ham storage methods</li>
            <li>New sausage recipes</li>
            <li>The nutritional value of duck meat</li>
            <li>Turkey cooking methods</li>
            <li>The supply of venison is increasing</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <h2 class="sticky">Fish</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Salmon farming techniques are improving</li>
            <li>Tuna catch volumes are increasing</li>
            <li>Cod cooking methods are gaining attention</li>
            <li>Squid consumption is surging</li>
            <li>The health benefits of shrimp</li>
            <li>Crab market prices are stable</li>
            <li>Mackerel storage methods</li>
            <li>The high nutritional value of flounder</li>
            <li>New mackerel cooking ideas</li>
            <li>Sardine catch volumes are increasing</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

CSS：
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.group {
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
.sticky {
    position: sticky;
    right: 0;
}

/* Additional styles for visibility */
.sticky {
    background: #3ea4b8;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
li {
    padding: 1em;
}

Workarounds I've Tried:

Added the following CSS to .sticky:

-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
will-change: transform;


Added the following CSS to html and body:

overscroll-behavior: none;



.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.group {
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
.sticky {
    position: sticky;
    right: 0;
}

/* Additional styles for visibility */
.sticky {
    background: #3ea4b8;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
li {
    padding: 1em;
}
<div class="container">
    <div class="group">
        <h2 class="sticky">Fruits</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Apple harvest has begun</li>
            <li>A new variety of grapes has been introduced</li>
            <li>Orange imports are increasing</li>
            <li>The nutritional value of bananas is being reassessed</li>
            <li>The mango season has arrived</li>
            <li>Cherry prices are rising</li>
            <li>The health benefits of pineapples</li>
            <li>How to chill watermelon</li>
            <li>New melon recipes</li>
            <li>Strawberry storage methods</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <h2 class="sticky">Vegetables</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Tomato cultivation techniques are evolving</li>
            <li>A new variety of cucumbers is gaining attention</li>
            <li>The health benefits of cabbage are being reassessed</li>
            <li>How to keep lettuce fresh</li>
            <li>The nutritional value of carrots has improved</li>
            <li>Broccoli cooking methods</li>
            <li>Spinach storage methods</li>
            <li>A bountiful potato harvest</li>
            <li>Eggplant popularity is surging</li>
            <li>Bell pepper cooking ideas</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <h2 class="sticky">Meat</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Beef consumption is increasing</li>
            <li>New cooking methods for pork</li>
            <li>Chicken prices are stable</li>
            <li>Lamb popularity is rising</li>
            <li>The health impacts of bacon</li>
            <li>Ham storage methods</li>
            <li>New sausage recipes</li>
            <li>The nutritional value of duck meat</li>
            <li>Turkey cooking methods</li>
            <li>The supply of venison is increasing</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <h2 class="sticky">Fish</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Salmon farming techniques are improving</li>
            <li>Tuna catch volumes are increasing</li>
            <li>Cod cooking methods are gaining attention</li>
            <li>Squid consumption is surging</li>
            <li>The health benefits of shrimp</li>
            <li>Crab market prices are stable</li>
            <li>Mackerel storage methods</li>
            <li>The high nutritional value of flounder</li>
            <li>New mackerel cooking ideas</li>
            <li>Sardine catch volumes are increasing</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>




Could you make a runnable snippet (use <> in the editor) so we can easily try it on IOS?

I tried it, but with this method, the bug didn't reproduce because it's displayed in an iFrame. I have made it available for confirmation on Netlify.

I can’t see the problem with ‘normal’ use but if I slightly zoom in and then scroll FISH heading occasionally disappears (on Netify not in the snippet).

Thank you for confirming this.
You are right, it comes on and off.
Do you know of any workaround or alternative?
